# Js escape special characters

Tags: javascript, php, html, escaping, alert

I've always escaped non-ASCII characters (such as `à`, `ñ`, `é`) as HTML entities (`&agrave;`, `&entilde;`, `&eacute;`), even if I'm using charset UTF-8 (just for text editor support and semplicity).

My problem is that I keep all the text in external PHP files for a multi-language purpose.

The problem comes when I have to escape strings which have to be alerted:

This `<button onclick="alert('&agrave;&egrave;&igrave;&ograve;&ugrave;')">Click me</button>` outputs this: `àèìòù`,

while this `<script>alert("&agrave;&egrave;&igrave;&ograve;&ugrave;")</script>` outputs this: `&agrave ;&egrave ;&igrave ;&ograve ;&ugrave ;`.

---

Which is the reason for it?

Since I want to escape characters in the second example too, how could I do that in a way supported by both examples?

Comment: The _JavaScript_ interpreter doesn't know _HTML_ entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those escaped chars are only readable by HTML.

A quick and dirty way if you want to handle them in the JS code (with JQuery though) is by adding them to an element and reading the output, otherwise if you just want to display your output somewhere in the page, it's super easy :)

See both examples below:

```js
var myString = "&agrave;&egrave;&igrave;&ograve;&ugrave;";

var escaped = $('<textarea />').html(myString).text();
alert(escaped);

document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = myString;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myElement">a</span>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to escape a non-ASCII character in a JS readable way? (something like `\n` for the line-break)

Comment: `echo json_encode("àèìòù");` prints `"\u00e0\u00e8\u00ec\u00f2\u00f9"` that should be easy for a `console.log("\u00e0\u00e8\u00ec\u00f2\u00f9")` to print `àèìòù`

Comment: thanks, I also found [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) out which helped